# Make target variable causes not input files

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use the following in a makefile, but when I type `make filter_test` it gives me the error below, and I can not figure out why. Note the spaces where the input files should be.

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-O1 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g
DEPS=p2.o recursive.o $@.cpp

p2.o: p2.cpp ; $(CXXFLAGS) -c p2.cpp

recursive.o: recursive.cpp ; $(CXXFLAGS) -c recursive.cpp

filter_test:  p2.o $@.cpp recursive.o ; $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) recursive.o p2.o $@.cpp  -o aaa
```

Output:

```
g++ -O1 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -g         -o .cpp
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.cpp] Error 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$@` only has a value inside the recipe, so when `make` sees `$@` in the prerequisite list, it treats it as an empty string.  So make is trying to build the pre-requisite `.cpp` and using the default rule to build it.  To fix this just write:

```
filter_test: p2.o filter_test.cpp recursive.o
```

Leave the recipe blank and let make use default rules.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know it is only valid within the recipe. When you say "let make use default rules", what do you mean by default rules?

Comment: If you do not specify a recipe, `make` has default rules for building an executable from similarly named files with .o, .c, .cpp, any many other suffixes.  That rule will use variables like `$CC`, `$CCFLAGS`, etc.